# Force rerender parent component when done with update data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data stored in an array of objects that will be sent through axios PUT. After done with updating data, I want the page to rerender so that it display the current data after update.

Parent component:-

```
<tbody>
  {appSettingsList.map((appSettings, i) => (
   <EditButton appSettings={appSettings} i={i} />
   ))}
</tbody>
```

first child component:-

```
const [showEdit, setShowEdit] = useState(false);
return (
<tr key={i}>
  <td>{appSettings.appid}</td>
  <td>{appSettings.Name}</td>
  <td>{appSettings.BackgroundColor}</td>
  <td>{appSettings.FontSize}</td>
  <td>{appSettings.FontFamily}</td>
  <td>{appSettings.Theme}</td>
  <td>{appSettings.NavigationBar}</td>
  <td className="action-column">
    {showEdit ? (
      <EditApplicationSettings
        appSettings={appSettings}
        changeState={(showEdit) => setShowEdit(showEdit)}
      />
    ) : (
      <button
        key={i}
        className="button-green"
        onClick={() => setShowEdit(!showEdit)}
      >
        Edit
      </button>
    )}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Second child component (this is where the update occurs)

```
const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState([]);
  const [attributeId, setAttributeId] = useState([]);
  let attributes = {
    appid: [],
    attributeid: [],
    newvalue: [],
    datemodified: [],
  };

function submitUpdate(e) {
e.preventDefault();
for (var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
  attributes.appid = appSettings.appid;
  attributes.attributeid = attributeId[i];
  attributes.newvalue = newValue[i];
  attributes.datemodified = GetCurrentLocalDateTime();
  axios
    .put(
      `http://localhost:8080/application-settings/${appSettings.appid}`,
      {
        attributes,
      }
    )
    .catch((error) =>
      console.log(
        "Failed to update employment type data",
        error.response.data
      )
    );
}
Swal.fire({
   icon: "success",
   title: "Successfully Updated!",
   showConfirmButton: false,
   timer: 1500,
});
props.changeState(false);
```

How to make the component rerender without having to force refresh on the whole page?

Comment: What component do you want to update? Why? The two solutions to virtually all problems in react are 1) don't mutate things and 2) lift state up. I imagine you just need to lift state up here.

Comment: @Adam I want to update the list of data that are displayed here (in this case the data display in parent component). This is to reflect the newly updated edit data that user input.

Comment: It's really hard to understand because you just pasted portions of the body of your components. But, you need to have `appSettings` as state somewhere. And, in that same component, you need to put your callback to call the server and update those settings. When the response returns from the server, you need to update the state in that component.